# how to get a list of all the constants that one can get from the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I get a list of global constants in a rails app (like ENV)? Something like:

```
>constants
```

I looked through

```
> puts methods
```

but didn't see anything that jumped out at me but I suspsect that there was something there.

thx in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Module.constants` may help you.

Comment: hmm.. thx... didn't know about this. Not exactly what I'm looking for but I think this is the closest. Probably need to reword question better (my fault)